# How do I load html into a webview?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I have just re-designed my iPhone app using Storyboard... questin is:  how do I address the the UIWebView so I can load the html?  (I am a newbie when it comes to Obj-C, having done my previous app in MonoTouch, so I'm kinda lost).  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Developer docs are really good resource. The usage of UIWebView is outlined here [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html)

To load a network resource simply pass a NSURLRequest object to loadRequest.

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest 
    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]]];
```

You can also do this in `viewDidLoad` (a `UIWebView` is a subclass of `UIView` and inherits all its methods). For example, loading a local pdf resource.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPhone_User_Guide" ofType:@"pdf"];
    if (thePath) {
        NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        [(UIWebView *)self.view loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
            textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter... I have two (2) UIWebViews... how do I differentiate between them?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.stackoverflow.com”;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
   NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: So where do I put this?  and how does XCode know which webView I'm referring to? (I have two of them in my app)

Comment: Create an iboutlet in your code and link it to the correct webview in interface builder

Comment: I hate to say this, but I can't seem to create the outlet.  I have highlighted the uiWebView, placed my cursor over it, did  a right click and then did a drag to the ViewController.h file.  nothing! (it bounces back)...

Comment: I just tried connecting to the ViewController icon on the bottom of the view contoller... it created a delegate... now what do I do with that?

Answer (score 0):

To setup your UIWebView with a link, just use the following code.

```
    var URLPath = "Insert email address here"
```

Then use...

```
    loadAddressURL()
```

and finally...

```
    func loadAddressURL(){

        let requestURL = NSURL(string:URLPath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        Webview.loadRequest(request)

    }
```